# React redirect asyc and await doesn't wait

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await

I have a following code where I want to grab an access token from url and put it the session storage and let my child component use the access token to get my information. However, when component loads first time it doesn't seem to find the access token but works if I refresh it again. In an attempt to resolve this issue I thought of using async / await so that it doesn't proceed further to redirect to child component until session token is not set but this doesn't seem to wait for token to be set. Not sure what am I doing wrong ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.processToken();
}

componentDidMount() {
   const { user } = this.props; 
   const { accessToken } = user;
   // expecting access token to print here by it is not
   console.log('user token : ', accessToken);
}
 processToken = async () => {
try {
    const params = querySearch(this.props.location.search);
    if('accessToken' in params){
       await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
          this.setOrderContext(params);
           resolve();
       } );  
        this.props.history.push(`/myinfo`);
    }
} catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex);
}
```

}

```
   setOrderContext (params){
     //this action calls a reducer and put the token in session storage
     this.props.userActions.processUserToken({data: {accessToken:params.accessToken}});
```

}

```
render() {
    return (

        <Switch>
            //myinfo component needs accessToken to retrieve my info
            <Route path="/myInfo" component={InofUI.App} />
        </Switch>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

```
class App extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
   this.processToken();

}
 processToken = () => {
    try {
        const params = querySearch(this.props.location.search);
        if('accessToken' in params){
            this.setOrderContext(params);
            this.props.history.push(`/myinfo`);
        }
    } catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
    }

   setOrderContext (params){
     //this action calls a reducer and put the token in session storage
     this.props.userActions.processUserToken({data: {accessToken:params.accessToken}});
}

render() {
    return (

        <Switch>
            //myinfo component needs accessToken to retrieve my info
            <Route path="/myInfo" component={InofUI.App} />
        </Switch>

    );
}
```

And then inside InfoUI.App

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieveMyInfo();
    }

    retrieveMyInfo = async () => {
        await this.untilTokenIsSet();
        const { location, history } = this.props;
        this.props.processUser(location, history);
    }

    untilTokenIsSet= () => {
        const poll = (resolve) => {
            const { user } = this.props;
            const { accessToken } = user;
            console.log('getting accessToken', accessToken);
            if (accessToken) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log('wating for token .. ');
                setTimeout(() => poll(resolve), 100);
            }
        };
        return new Promise(poll);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the call of `this.processToken()` inside your constructor. Since you don't and can't wait for this call, React simply calls the method and continues with its lifecycle.
Therefore it might be that `componentDidMount` is called before your `setOrderContext` finished.

As always in a React environment you should fetch resources and make asynchronous calls inside of `componentDidMount`. This assures that your component renders smooth and correct before any external resources are accessed.

What you want to do is to move your `this.processToken()` call from the constructor to the `componentDidMount` method and make sure it is handled correctly there.